# Evaluate $\int\frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int\frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}dx$ what is my $z$? I know that $x=z^n$ and $n$ is the LCD of the exponents, but my lcd here is just one? so my $z$ is gonna be $z=x^2+1$? but I saw the notes of my classmate its $z^2=x^2+1$ can someone explain this thoroughly please

Comment: Let $z=x^2+1$, so $dz=2xdx$ and $x^2=z-1$.

Comment: you mean to say my classmate notes is wrong?

Comment: If you let $z=x^2+1$, you will get $\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{z-1}{z^3}dz=\frac{1}{2}\int(z^{-2}-z^{-3})$, so it will work fine.

Comment: Try manipulating the integral as follows before substituting.
$$\int\frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}dx=\int\frac{x^2(2x)}{2(x^2+1)^3}dx=\int\frac{((x^2+1)-1)(2x)}{2(x^2+1)^3}dx$$

Noting that $d(x^2+1)/dx = 2x$, it should be crystal clear now that $z=x^2+1$ is the appropriate substitution.

Answer (score 2):

If you substitute $z^2=x^2+1$ , $2zdz=2xdx$ then $$\int\frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}dx =\int\frac{z^2-1}{z^6}zdz = \int(\frac{1}{z^3}-\frac{1}{z^5})dz$$

Comment: How about just $z=x^2+1$ so you get $dz=2xdx$ and $\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{z-1}{z^3}dz$.

Comment: both ways work fine. just choose whichever you prefer.